# Can a Windows Gadget save data?

Tags: windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm creating a small Windows Sidebar Gadget for taking notes in a simple `textarea`.

[image]

I have, as usual, a `gadget.xml` manifest file and a `.html` file, see below.

**How is it possible to read some data / save some data in a Gadget?**

I know this is usually impossible with JavaScript only (*note: using `localstorage` is not possible because I want persistance of data*), so **how to save/read data inside a `Windows Gadget` ?**

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode" />
        <title>NeverForget</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            margin: 0;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;            
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        #gadgetContent 
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: none;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/jscript" language="jscript">
            function init() {
                // how to load notes from a file here on startup?
            }
            window.onkeydown = function () {
                // how to save data to file?
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init()">
            <textarea id="gadgetContent">Bonjour</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these:

1. There are the inbuilt [methods of the System.Gadget.Settings object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486214(v=vs.85).aspx) which can be used to to read/write from the Settings.ini file (stored in C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar) but this information will be lost if the gadget is closed or uninstalled.
2. Use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat(v=vs.85).aspx) to create or read or write folders/files anywhere. Limitation: file can only be saved as unicode or ascii.
3. Use an [ADO Stream object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677486(v=vs.85).aspx) to create or read or write files anywhere. Limitation: can't create folders - must be used in conjunction with the FileSystemObject. Advantage: can use any codepage that exists on your computer.

Since I like saving text files with utf-8 the example below uses the third method but you may well decide to dispense with some of the error handling. (NB - this example is based on a [script published by Andrew Urquhart](http://andrewu.co.uk/clj/load_and_save_file_helper_functions/))

Fortunately the sidebar is able to use [knownfolders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486317(v=vs.85).aspx) and [knownfolderpaths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486318(v=vs.85).aspx) so finding the path to your documents folder for example is as easy as

```
var docs = System.Shell.knownFolderPath("Documents");
```

Remember that the backslash is an escape character in javascript so that paths in strings must have their backslashes doubled.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>NeverForget</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {margin:0;width:300px;height:200px;background-color:transparent;padding:10px;}
#gadgetContent {width:280px;height:144px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black;background-color:#eee;}
button {margin-left:66px;margin-top:10px;}
#message {display:none;width:280px;height:180px;position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px;background-color:#eee;border:1px solid red;}
#messageContent {width:278px;height:144px;word-wrap:break-word;overflow-y:auto;}
#newButton {position:absolute;bottom:10px;left:54px;}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/jscript">
//globals
var myFolderPath=System.Shell.knownFolderPath("Documents")+"\\myFiles";
//end globals
function showMessage(msg){
 message.style.display="block";
 messageContent.innerText=msg;
}
function closeMessage(){
 message.style.display="none";
 messageContent.innerText="";
}
function loadFile(strAbsoluteFilePath, strCharSet){
 var adReadAll=-1, adReadLine=-2, strFileContents="", objStream=new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream"), fso=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 try{
  if(!strAbsoluteFilePath){
   throw new Error(1, "Required parameter \"strAbsoluteFilePath\" was not defined");
  }
  if(!strCharSet){
   throw new Error(2, "Required parameter \"strCharSet\" was not defined");
  }
  if(!fso.FolderExists(myFolderPath)){
   throw new Error(3, "Folder \""+myFolderPath+"\" does not exist");
  }
  objStream.Open();
  try{
   objStream.CharSet=strCharSet;
   objStream.LoadFromFile(strAbsoluteFilePath);
   strFileContents=objStream.ReadText(adReadAll);
   gadgetContent.innerText=strFileContents;
  }
  catch(err){
   throw new Error(err.number, "Loading failed:\r\n" + err.description);
  }
  finally{
   objStream.Close(); // Always close the stream regardless of what happens
   objStream=null;
   fso=null;
  }
 }
 catch(err){
  showMessage("Function loadFile() failed with parameters strAbsoluteFilePath=\"" + strAbsoluteFilePath + "\", strCharSet=\"" + strCharSet + "\". Message=\r\n" + err.description+"\r\nError Number: "+err.number);
 }
}
function saveFile(strAbsoluteFilePath, strCharSet, strFileContents, blnOverwrite){
 var adSaveCreateNotExist=1, adSaveCreateOverWrite=2, objStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream"), fso=new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
 try{
  if(!strAbsoluteFilePath){
   throw new Error(1, "Required parameter \"strAbsoluteFilePath\" was not defined");
  }
  if(!strCharSet){
   throw new Error(2, "Required parameter \"strCharSet\" was not defined");
  }
  if(typeof strFileContents != "string"){
   throw new Error(3, "Required parameter \"strFileContents\" was not a string");
  }
  if(!fso.FolderExists(myFolderPath)){
   fso.CreateFolder(myFolderPath);
  }
  objStream.Open();
  try{
   objStream.CharSet=strCharSet;
   objStream.WriteText(strFileContents);
   objStream.SaveToFile(strAbsoluteFilePath, (blnOverwrite ? adSaveCreateOverWrite : adSaveCreateNotExist));
   return true;
  }
  catch(err){
   throw new Error(err.number, "SaveToFile failed:\r\n" + err.description);
  }
  finally{
   objStream.Close(); // Always close the stream regardless of what happens
   objStream=null;
   fso=null;
  }
  return false;
 }
 catch(err){
  showMessage("Function saveFile() failed with parameters strAbsoluteFilePath=\"" + strAbsoluteFilePath + "\", strCharSet=\"" + strCharSet + "\", strFileContents=\"" + strFileContents + "\", blnOverwrite=\"" + blnOverwrite + "\". Message=\r\n" + err.description+"\r\nError Number: "+err.number);
 }
}
function init(){
 loadButton.onclick=function(){loadFile(myFolderPath+"\\myFile.txt","utf-8");};
 saveButton.onclick=function(){saveFile(myFolderPath+"\\myFile.txt", "utf-8", gadgetContent.innerText, true);};
 closeButton.onclick=closeMessage;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
 <textarea id="gadgetContent">Bonjour</textarea>
 <div id="message">
  <div id="messageContent"></div>
  <div id="newButton"><button id="closeButton">Close</button></div>
 </div>
 <button id="loadButton">Load</button><button id="saveButton">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Waw thanks so much @mystifeid! This is really great! Last thing: how to make the textbox and the body totally transparent? ie we see the Desktop under the text, and no white/grey background.

Comment: Try using a 1px x 1px transparent png as a g:background (see Remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486136.aspx) for how to declare in html) then size it to 100% width and height (of the body size) in your onload function.(ie:  imgBackground.style.width="100%"; imgBackground.style.height="100%";)

Comment: Black text added via html or normal javascript methods is likely to appear magenta in colour when using a transparent g:background. You might be able to resolve this by adding/removing text as [g:text objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486146.aspx). This, btw, is outside the scope of your original question. Please try searching, reading and having a decent attempt yourself. If, after a few days, you can make no more progress, ask another question and provide your css/script/html.